# Check alignment of SSD

Tags: ssd

I did a migration of my OS from HDD to SSD on Windows 7 using its backup and restore utility. How can I check if the SSD is aligned properly?

Answer (score 2):

If the original drive was partition with Windows 7, and you didn't used any third-part tools, then it is almost certainly aligned properly.  But if you want to know, just boot a linux livecd and run `fdisk -l -u`.  If the first partition starts on `2048`, then everything is fine, if it starts on `63` something is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 6.0+ will not align on anything but 1 MB boundaries by default.